# Powershell - Trouble removing Windows User profiles older than 7 days

Tags: powershell

I find a lot of answers to my technical questions on this site but just signed up to ask my first question as I can't find an answer. I'm using powershell to try to remove user profiles older than 7 days from Windows 10 PCs. This is my code:

```
    ForEach ($PCName In [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($PCtxtfile))
{
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Computer $PCName | Where {(!$_.Special) -and (!$_.Loaded) -and ($_.LocalPath -notmatch 'defaultuser0|admin|administrator' ) -and ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTIme) -lt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-7))} | Remove-WMIObject
}
```

If I remove the last conditional part (ie. the data-time clause), this code works to remove all profiles (except the special ones as shown):

```
    ForEach ($PCName In [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($PCtxtfile))
{
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Computer $PCName | Where {(!$_.Special) -and (!$_.Loaded) -and ($_.LocalPath -notmatch 'defaultuser0|admin|administrator' )} | Remove-WMIObject
}
```

So it's meant to cycle thru the list of PCs in the text file and it works without the 7 day clause. When running that code, it doesn't remove any profiles at all. Wondered if anyone had any thoughts or suggestions please, with my sincere thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! Hint: Where are you removing the wmiobject on? :)

Comment: Hiya, Thank you for your reply. The script takes the PC name from a text file and should remove profiles from the PC variable "$PCName". The first command is meant to get the date 7 days before today and compare that to the date the user profile was last used.

Comment: Are you sure `Get-WMIObject` is passing the `ComputerName` argument through the pipeline to `Remove-WMIObject`?

Comment: Another hint from [`MS Docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1): `-ComputerName:` **Accept pipeline input: False**

Comment: Santiago, the same script works if one removes:  -and ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTIme) -lt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-7))

Comment: Is there a method of `$PCName` called **ConvertToDateTime**? I highly doubt it. Maybe `$_.LastUseTIme` does so the syntax should be `$_.LastUseTIme.ConvertToDateTime()`. Either way use the `Get-Member` cmdlet to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closure bracket (see bold/italian one added just before -lt), and needed to remove last closure bracket, otherways it seems to work fine:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Computer $PCName | Where {(!$_.Special) -and (!$_.Loaded) -and ($_.LocalPath -notmatch 'defaultuser0|admin|administrator' ) -and ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime)***)*** -lt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-7)} | Remove-WMIObject
```

Best regards
Kris

Comment: Please use code block for better reading and appearance